# Migrating Windows installation from a dying SSD

Tags: windows, backup, ssd

My SSD seems like it is about to die.
The SSD in this case is my boot drive, running Win 7 64bit.

Whats the easiest way to migrate to a new SSD?
Should I use a clone tool to clone the disk? If so which one would you recommend?

Also since the new SSD will probably be of different capacity and manufacturer than current SSD, wont the cloned image have incorrect info on it and thus prevent booting?

Comment: use xxclone : http://www.xxclone.com/idwnload.htm or EaseUs Disk Copy : http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/ it handles SSD disks with different capacities and clones them properly. So ideally it should boot properly.

Comment: First thing, right now, create a backup of your important files on anything you have handy. robocopy is an adequate tool for this. The universe tends toward maximum irony. Don't push it.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSD you are currently using starts throwing errors/causing issues I'd advise against using a clone tool as you might transfer existing issues to your new system.

My advice would be to backup all data and setup a new windows installation from scratch on your new ssd. You then can move back the data you need from the backup.

Comment: Only if it's logical errors on the disk structure. If (s)he has unrecoverable bad sectors making an mirror image is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

0) What ever you do, don't reboot your machine if not really necessary. Keep it on. Disable automatic shutdown.

1) Buy Spinrite and run it at level 1. This is read-only and it will force the disk to re-allocate bad sectors when found (and if still possible)

2) Clone the disk, swap the disks. Windows is pretty good at handling the new (larger) zize. Just go into Computer/Manage to resize the partition or make a new one.

Comment: Spinright wouldn't work on an SSD http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-194.txt - search for 'SpinRite is all about mechanics and magnetics, neither of which exist in, by design, in an SSD' - according to Steve Gibson himself

Comment: You are 144 episodes behind ;-) "It is the case, however, that running a SpinRite Level 1 pass over an SSD is good for it." http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-338.txt